# How to run profile specific test cases with junit in Maven?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have multiple profiles in my Java Project. Each of them handles exclusive sets of requests. When I build project for a selected profile, I want to run tests that are relevant to only that profile. Is the possible to do with some sort of Junit or Maven configuration?

Answer (score 2):

you can configure multiply profiles with maven and for each have it's own
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes

also you can change http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testSourceDirectory or use http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#groups